# Does ** have any meaning in Java?

Tags: java, android, syntax

What does the following statement mean?

```
INT_MAX**1/3
```

For context I saw this in an Android coding challenge, where it also treats `2^11` as meaning '2 to the power of 11' (instead of 2 XOR 11), so it is possible it's pseudocode:

> Lets look at the number of valid possibilities for A^B.
>
> For B = 2, number of possibilities = sqrt(INT_MAX) = sqrt(2^31 - 1) < 2^16.
>
> For B = 3, number of possibilities = INT_MAX**1/3 < 2^11

Comment: It means you're about to get a syntax error? `**` isn't [an operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in Java, so I'd say it's highly likely it's pseudocode.

Comment: That's not Java.

Comment: In other languages, `**` can mean floating-point exponentiation.

Comment: I had thought it was not valid. Do either of you know what it means in the context of the quote I added?

Comment: @NickCardoso It looks like you've guilted a couple people into upvoting. In all honesty though, your question seems badly researched.

Comment: Try searching 'what does ** mean in pseudocde' on in Java and 'what is ** in mathematics'. None give any useful results. (and in the future, they will list this. Precisely what StackOverflow is intended for)

Comment: @NickCardoso searching for a thing which doesn't exist is unlikely to yield results. You could have searched for "Java operators", and got a list of [all operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12), of which `**` is not one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `**` operator in Java. This is probably pseudocode that borrows from Python's syntax, where `**` is the exponentiation operator - i.e. `MAX_INT**1/3` is "`MAX_INT` to the power of a third", or the cube root of `MAX_INT`.